# How to deploy Laravel 5.2.* on IBM Bluemix cloud?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ibm-cloud

I have developed an application using Laravel 5.2 and I have tried to deploy the application using old documents available on IBM Bluemix cloud, but those documents didn't provide a solution to deploy my application. Please can anyone provide step-by-step instructions on how to upload the Laravel 5.2 application to the IBM Bluemix cloud?

Answer (score 0):

There is a LAMP-stack image available at the community app catalog that contains Laravel 5 (along with other frameworks). You could use this one when creating a new Virtual machine:

https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/download/openstack/bitnami-lampstack-5.4.40-0-ubuntu-14.04.qcow

Once deployed you will first have to upgrade it to Laravel 5.1 by following the update documentation provided by bitnami.

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP_Frameworks/Laravel#Upgrading_to_Laravel_5.1

When that is done, you can follow the upgrade documentation at Laravel to upgrade from L5.1 to L5.2:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0